# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence - Sorting data in a text file

Tags: python, list, sorting

My code so far , however when i attempt to run it. it presents me with the error code `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`.

The data in the text file is ordered like this:

```
Kevin 2 3 6 
Mary 8 6 6 
Ollie 9 7 3
```

My code dosent seem to alphabetically order this set and or sort it highest to lowest score.

```
from __future__ import division
from operator import attrgetter


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores
        self.highscore = max(scores)
        self.avgscore = sum(scores) / len(scores)

with open('classFilea.txt') as f:
    players = []
    for line in f:
        elems = line.split(',')
        players.append(Player(elems[0], map(int, elems[1:])))

    byhighscore = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('highscore'), reverse=True)
    byavg = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('avgscore'), reverse=True)

    print('')
    for p in byhighscore:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.highscore))

    print('')
    for p in byavg:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.avgscore))
```

Comment: `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` indicates that `scores` for some line is empty

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the argument "scores" in the constructor is empty. So, there's a line in your file which doesn't have a ',' in it.

I'll take a wild guess and say there's an empty line at the end of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Something must be going wrong / unexpected data format on this line:

```
players.append(Player(elems[0], map(int, elems[1:])))
```

Which is causing an error on this line:

```
self.highscore = max(scores)
```

Whatever `map(int, elems[1:])` is returning is an empty sequence. Try adding a `print` statement just before there, or `print(name, scores)` in your `Player` class to help diagnose where the problem is.